# using Eval() to check checkboxes based on input field

Tags: asp.net

can someone please explain the meaning of the following line

```
<%#Eval("MType").ToString() == "0" ? "&nbsp;" : "<input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"cb_Show_" + Eval("MType") + "_" + Eval("ID") + "\" " + ((bool)Eval("IsShow") ? "checked" : "") + " />" %>
```

All checkboxes are checked based on the above fields. Can someone please tell how eval works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eval is "evaluating" those variables to help render the desired content. I think it's usually done inside a databound control.  The # sign indicates the databinding.

You also have a ternary operator used here (the ?).  It's very powerful and useful to keep code tighter and succinct.

So in the first part if MType is equal to 0 when converted to a string, then it will show a space, otherwise it will show an input box.

The input box has other attribute changes to it based on the Eval()'s as well.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!